# Assigned width in percentage but want to get it in pixels

Tags: jquery, html, css

```css
.test {
  border: 1px solid;
  cursor: pointer;
  height: 10px;
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div id="test1" class="test"></div>
```

I have displayed my HTML `id` and its CSS. Now when I am doing `$('#test').width()` I am getting `100`. I want its `width` in pixels (not in `%`).

Can anyone tell how to get its width in pixels?

Comment: Related GitHub issue https://github.com/jquery/jquery/issues/3455

Comment: @kukkuz Yeah, I used the fiddle in one of the answers below. In my case I do not have `display:none` set but do have a complicated page. I'm trying to recreate a simple fiddle but unable to do so so far.

Comment: @MuhammadRehanSaeed, what result do you have when calling `element.getBoundingClientRect().width` or even just `element.clientWidth`?

Comment: edited answer so that it does contain enough detail. I think it solves your problem easily even under a hidden parent or any kind of ancestor.

Comment: @MuhammadRehanSaeed element.clientWidth returned 0 (if i remember i run it on Hoznik's example, on the question's code it returned 100)

Comment: @Denzz, Kalle gives the correct answer below why isn't that the accepted answer? document.getElementById('test1').clientWidth

Answer (score 24, accepted):

`.width()` gets "...the current computed width" of the element that is used on, per the jQuery width documentation: http://api.jquery.com/width/, so the return value from `$('#heatMapBar').width()` is in pixels, not percent. I would suggest using developers tool to check the width, it may be that in `#heatMapBar`'s current context, its width is 100px.

If you look here: http://jsfiddle.net/NkQXa/1/ you will see that `#test` is set to `width:50%;`, but it alerts the actual pixel width.

Comment: But I am able to see that its width is near to 700 px in actual

Comment: @user1424564 If you look here: http://jsfiddle.net/NkQXa/1/, you'll see that I've put in your exact test case and get a pixel width. The problem may be elsewhere.

Comment: True! It is due to time. I checked the same width after some seconds then its showing me proper width. So may be the time I was calling it was not proper.Thanks

Comment: This will not work with responsive designs.  Returns the percentage.

Comment: `.width()` is giving me `39.4` ... but it should be about 400 .... .... then I checked `.css('width')` which returned `"39.4%"` ... ... ... ... ... see @honzik's answer below to explain why

Comment: JQuery (v3.1.1) returns the percentage if you query the value too early (within angular for me) and in your CSS you specified a percentage.

Comment: @Denzz @tibc-dev @dsdsdsdsd @DJDaveMark Waiting for DOM ready `$(function() { ... })` does not work but using a `setTimeout` to wait for a bit and try again does. Did any of you figure out a better solution?

Comment: Great explanation... So how do you get it in pixels like he asked?

Answer (score 39):

One of options can be too, that parent element is not visible.
Here is example:  http://jsfiddle.net/nDMM3/

You can see, that jQuery return width = 100 (like 100%)

```
.test {
    border: 1px solid;
    cursor: pointer;
    height: 10px;
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    display:none;
}

#test2{
   width:100%;
}

<div id="test1" class="test">
   <div id="test2">
      Hello
   </div>    
 </div>   

 alert($('#test2').width());
```

Comment: Don't suppose anyone came up with a clever way to fix this, did they?

Comment: @mituw16 +1 For a solution to this apart from using a `setTimeout` and trying it again a little later.

Answer (score 5):

There can be a problem with multiple divs having percentage width:

```
<div style="width: 50%">
<div id="getMyWidth" style="width: 100%"></div>
</div>
```

In this case it returns 100 as width for the inner div for me. I solved it by taking the width of the outer div.

Comment: this happens a lot in Bootstrap grid layouts, since you're not really setting a width, you're setting a `class="span12"` or whatever. I agree, the easiest thing is just to get the width of the outermost parent div.

Answer (score 3):

Based on ***Honzik's*** answer there this is a small workaround in case the element needed to specify it's width is inside a hidden parent element.

```
function getWidth(elemID) {
    // get parent element unique id (must have)
    var parentId = $("#"+elemID).parent().prop("id"); 
    // remove the child element based on the specified element id
    $("#"+elemID).remove();
    // append a new child element but on body where most probably is not set to "display:none"
    $("body").append('<div id="'+elemID+'">Hello</div>');
    // get the width of the newly appended child element and store it to a variable
    var width = $("#test2").width();
    // remove child element from body
    $("#"+elemID).remove();
    // re-append child element to its former position under former parent element (having CSS attribute "display:none")
    $(parentId).append('<div id="'+elemID+'">Hello</div>');
    // display stored element width 
    alert(width);
}
// usage to get the element's width
getWidth("test2");
```

> Try it in the below snippet!

```js
function getWidth(elemID) {
        var parentId = $("#"+elemID).parent().prop("id"); // your parent element should have a unique id specified
        $("#"+elemID).remove();
        $("body").append('<div id="'+elemID+'">Hello</div>');
        var width = $("#test2").width();
        $("#"+elemID).remove();
        $(parentId).append('<div id="'+elemID+'">Hello</div>');
        alert(width);
    }
getWidth("test2");
```

```css
.test {
    border: 1px solid;
    cursor: pointer;
    height: 10px;
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    display:none;
}

#test2{
   width:100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="test1" class="test">
   <div id="test2">
      Hello
   </div>    
 </div>
```

Answer (score 3):

Another solution without jquery is to use the property `clientWidth` available on HTMLElements

```
document.getElementById('test1').clientWidth
```

Answer (score 2):

That can be a co-incidence .
According to the official documentation on [api.jqery.com](http://api.jquery.com/width/) , it states that

> Get the current computed width for the first element in the set of matched elements.

To confirm that you are getting the width in pixels , you can equate this value to .css(width) method of jQuery . 
It returns the width in pixels and hence , you can confirm that the return height is in Pixels.

Answer (score 2):

**Just an idea...don't hate**. I know it doesn't cover every eventuality but something like [this](http://codepen.io/tenmilebrenty/pen/qqvrLX) could check each of the items parents for the desired css rules *(display:none; in this case)*. I got the idea from [here](http://api.jquery.com/outerwidth/).

The only problem is when a site gets more complicated...it becomes slow.

But it's a jumping off point.

```
//showing as 100%
alert($('#test2').width());
//use window.load to ensure .width() isnt doing anything funny
$(window).load(function(){
//checks to see if any of its parents have display:none; we can have multiple checks here if required
    if ($( "#test2" ).parents().css('display') == 'none') {
//iterate through each parent of the selected item  
        $( "#test2" ).parents().each(function () {
//only change the display value if the element has a display:none;
            if ($(this).css('display') == 'none') {
                $(this).css('display', 'block');
                alert($('#test2').width());//or whatever we want to do with this number
//reset values here       
                $(this).css('display', 'none');
           }
        });
    }
//showing as 100%
    alert($('#test2').width());
});
```

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure about this fact but `$("#id/.class").width()` gives the value in **pixels** in my case.

[image: screen-shot of jQuery code]

In above screen-shot you can find different values of `$("#id/.class").width()` in **pixels** at different screen size of browser.

> Well I'm using Firefox for this purpose.

*You can also check the [jquery documentation](http://api.jquery.com/width/) on this topic.*

Answer (score 2):

Pls check the code appended below, I hope this is the simplest way to get the width from percentage to pixel.

**HTML**

```
<div id="test1" class="test">
 <p id="widthPx"> Perentage to Pixel : </p>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
 .test {
  border: 1px solid;
  cursor: pointer;
  height: 100%;
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 10px;
}
```

**JS**

```
var widPx = $('#test1').width();
$('#widthPx').append(Math.round(widPx) + 'px');
```

**OUTPUT**

**Perentage to Pixel : 609px**

The output would be purely based on the div width.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It could have been a bug in earlier jQuery versions, up to this Github PR: https://github.com/jquery/jquery/pull/3741

Although it's 2019 now, I had to use jQuery 1.12.4 and noticed that width computation of a hidden (hidden by parent) element was always 100.

By debugging, I found that the jQuery outerWidth (similar for innerHeight, innerWidth, height, width, outerHeight and outerWidth) function will call the width cssHook, which in turn calls getWidthOrHeight(). getWidthOrHeight() may obtain a width in %, which is then returned as it is. The width function does not check what was returned and passes it through parseFloat, which results in the 100% becoming just 100.

Answer (score -1):

I think that should work, but if for some reason it keeps on giving you the % width, What you can do is get the width and then divide it by the window width

```
var widthInPx = $(widnow).width()/$('yourElement').width
```

Comment: Jeevan, I think your calculation is incorrect. It should be... `code` var widthInPx = $(window).width()/(100/$('yourElement').width()); `code`

Comment: @john T, not quite. cos width() is giving '100', ie percent, and 100/100=1, so you just end up with the window width. But yes, Jeevans' answer suffers from the same issue.

Comment: @GavinSimpson: And `1 * (window).width()` would be equal to the width of the window. Isn't that what 100% means?

Comment: I don't think so @jonathan Wood, as window.width() returns 100, i.e. a percentage as it's given in a percentage, so 1 * (window).width() is the same as 1 * 100, which is not the width in pixels.