# How to use % instead of px with draggable element?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm stucked and I need help. I'm making map with markers. I can add markers etc.
My main container have 100% width and height. When I click somewhere my marker has % values for example top: 34%; left: 35%;
After dragging marker new position have px value. I want to save % values.
Any ideas?

map.js

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){

// basic add

$("button#remove").click(function(){
$(".marker").remove();
});


//add with position
var map = $(".map");
var pid = 0;

function AddPoint(x, y, maps) {

    // $(maps).append('<div class="marker"></div>');
    var marker = $('<div class="marker ui-widget-content"></div>');
    marker.css({
        "left": x,
        "top": y
    });
    marker.attr("id", "point-" + pid++);
    $(maps).append(marker)
    $('.marker').draggable().resizable();
}
map.click(function (e) {
        // var x = e.pageX - this.offsetLeft;
        // var y = e.pageY - this.offsetTop;
        var x = e.offsetX/ $(this).width() * 100 + '%';
        var y = e.offsetY/ $(this).height() * 100 + '%';

        // $(this).append('<div class="marker"></div>');
        AddPoint(x, y, this);
});


// drag function
$(".ui-widget-content").draggable({
    drag: function( event, ui ) {
        var x = e.offsetX/ $(this).width() * 100 + '%';
        var y = e.offsetY/ $(this).height() * 100 + '%';
 }
});

});
```

style.css

```
.wrapper {
margin: 0 auto;
width: 100%;
min-height: 400px;
overflow: hidden;
}

.map {
width: 100%;
position: relative;
}

.map > img {
max-width: 100%;
max-height: 100%;
}
.marker {
width: 10px;
height: 10px;
border-radius: 50%;
background: rgba(255, 0, 0, 1);
position: absolute;
left: 50%;
top: 50%;
z-index: 999;
}

#mapa {
width: 30px;
height: 30px;
border-radius: 50%;
background: rgba(255, 0, 0, 1);
z-index: 999;   
}
```

some html code

```
    <div class="wrapper">
    <div class="map">
        <img src="http://i.imgur.com/HtxXGR5.jpg" width="100%" height="auto" margin="15px 0;" alt="">
    </div>
    <button id="remove">Remove all markers</button>
</div>
```

Comment: jfiddle wud have been better !

Comment: [here](http://jsfiddle.net/50g529m0/)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to capture the position, after the drag is ended (fire 1 time per drag) you can do this:

```
$('.marker').draggable({
    stop: function() {
       var offset =  $(this).offset();
       var mapOffest = $('.map').offset();

       var x = ((offset.left - mapOffest.left)/ ($(".map").width() / 100))+"%";
       var y = ((offset.top - mapOffest.top)/ ($(".map").height() / 100))+"%";

       // We need to do something with thoses vals uh?
       $(this).css('left', x);
       $(this).css('top', y);
       // or
       console.log('X:'+x + '||Y:'+y);
    }
});
```

[Fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/50g529m0/1/)

Take note that the event has been set on the marker directy, this was probably your mistake.

The little calcul needs to take care of the map offset, which you don't need if your map is a full width/height (window size)

If you need, or prefer use the `drag` event rather than the `stop`, theses lines won't have any effects

```
$(this).css('left', x);
$(this).css('top', y);
```

But you'll still be able to capture the position, the console values will be  goods.

Hope it may helps you.

Comment: strange thing. In fiddle works perfectly When I add this to my project and try to drag any marker it's just gone. And console log looks like this
X:739.734375%||Y:Infinity%

Comment: @MMPL1 Try to log each property (offset, mapOffeset and $('.map') to see which one   failed. Do you have any links we could visit?

Comment: nah. I have local version for now.
console.log(offset, mapOffest, $('.map')) give me this
Object {top: 521, left: 819.71875} Object {top: 340, left: 0} [div.map, div.map, prevObject: m.fn.init[1], context: document, selector: ".map"]

Comment: Please do `console.log($('.map').length());` and `console.log($('.map').width() + '|| ' + $('.map').height());`

Comment: console.log($('.map').length()); give me error
Uncaught TypeError: $(...).length is not a function on line 39 which is this console.log

second console.log give me that
100|| 0 and point is still sticky to the left

Comment: Yes mybad it was `$('.map').length`. Anyway we can see where the problem is, the height of the map is 0, here you can guess the problem. I don't know how we can get this result but take a look closely to the fiddle I gave you, check if the html structure is the same, or what css rules you have who can modify the map sizes. To be sure you can add a "static" size for the map (`.map { width: 200px; height: 200px; }` for example)

Comment: Hmm, I add height: 100% to my .map in css. Now console log give me this
100|| 100. So my map have 100% width and 100% height, right? And new position of marker after drag is left: 749.734375%; top: 237%;
And thanks for your help.

Comment: As we can see in this thread http://stackoverflow.com/q/17305707/4933917 There can be some cases that cause this issue. I'm nearly 100% the problem comes from an other part of your code. Can you try to put px size on the map and on the parent(s). It will be hard to help you more as I can't see your full code.

Comment: ok. Marker is no longer sticky but it return px position not %.

Comment: Ok, I changed my wrapper width to 400px, my .map width & height to 400px and .map > img width & height to 400px. Now after drag I have % values but still value is too big. It's like 180% etc. Maybe you want to help me through teamviewer or something?

Comment: Send me an email asap, just to say hi (look on my profile) We'll take a look together and give the answer here when we'll find out :)

Answer (score 0):

problem solved, DFayet thank's again
final code

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){

// basic add

$("button#remove").click(function(){
$(".marker").remove();
});


//add with position
var map = $(".map");
var pid = 0;

function AddPoint(x, y, maps) {

    var marker = $('<div class="marker"></div>');
    marker.css({
        "left": x,
        "top": y
    });
    marker.attr("id", "point-" + pid++);
    $(maps).append(marker);
    $('.marker').draggable({
        stop: function(event, ui) {
            var thisNew = $(this);

            var x = (ui.position.left / thisNew.parent().width()) * 100 + '%';
            var y = (ui.position.top / thisNew.parent().height()) * 100 + '%';

            thisNew.css('left', x);
            thisNew.css('top', y);

            console.log(x, y);
        }
    });
}
map.click(function (e) {
        var x = e.offsetX/ $(this).width() * 100 + '%';
        var y = e.offsetY/ $(this).height() * 100 + '%';
        AddPoint(x, y, this);
});

});
```