# jQuery width returns incorrect values

Tags: jquery, angularjs, slick.js

I am making slick carousel of line charts(using d3) and inside of directive, I need to set svg width. But `jQuery.width()` is returning wrong width.

HTML is:

```
<slick settings="halls" slides-to-show="4" slides-to-scroll="1"
       style="height: 100px;" ng-if="hall.lectures.length">
    <div class="col-lg-3" ng-repeat="lectureId in lectures"
        ng-init="data = getData(lectureId)">
        <lecture-multiple data="data.data" name="data.name" start="data.start" end="data.end"></lecture-multiple>
    </div>
</slick>
```

lectureMultiple.js:

```
angular.module('module')
.directive('lectureMultiple', [
    '$log',
    '$window',
    function ($log, $window) {
        return {
            restrict: 'E',
            scope: {
                data: '=',
                name: '=',
                start: '=',
                end: '='
            },
            link: function (scope, element) {
                $log.warn($(element[0]).parent());
                $log.warn($(element[0]).parent().outerWidth());
            }
        };
    }]);
```

Console logs 25 which is not a correct answer.

If you see something what I am doing wrong. Please comment.

Thank you.

Comment: Can you try putting width inside a timeout just in case dom is getting updated to get the correct width.

Comment: I tried to set 'col-lg-4' class and jQuery returns 33.333333. I looks like jQuery is returning percentage value, not pixel value. Is there some way to make jQuery return pixel value?

Comment: this may help u http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17305707/assigned-width-in-percentage-but-want-to-get-it-in-pixels

Comment: Yes, I read that. And it didn't help me though. I made every slick "image"(div) fixed width and it is working correctly. I just don't know why it returns value in percentage. I checked in developer console parent element and it has 141px width. And it returns 25. And when I change it to col-lg-4 it returns 33.33333. Maybe problem is not in jQuery. But I don't know why parent element has 100px width. I wasn't able to find element that has 100px width.